# Copy files from GCLOUD to S3 with SDK GCloud

Tags: amazon-s3, sdk, copy, boto, gcloud

I am trying to copy a file between gcloud and aws s3 with sdk gcloud console and it shows me an error. I have got the way to copy the gcloud file to a local directory (gsutil -D cp gs://mybucket/myfile C:\tmp\storage\file) and to upload this local file to s3 using aws cli (aws s3 cp C:\tmp\storage\file s3://my_s3_dirctory/file), and it works perfectly, but i would like to do all of this directly, with no need to download the files and only using SDK Gcloud console.

When i try to do this, the system shows me an error:

```
gsutil -D cp gs://mybucket/myfile s3://my_s3_dirctory/file.csv

Failure: Host [...] returned an invalid certificate. (remote hostname 
"....s3.amazonaws.com" does not match certificate)...
```

I have edited and uncommented that lines in .boto file, but the error continues:

```
# To add HMAC aws credentials for "s3://" URIs, edit and uncomment the
# following two lines:
aws_access_key_id = [MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]

aws_secret_access_key = [MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY]
```

I am a noob in this and i dont know what is boto and i have no idea if i am editing it well or not. I dont know if i can to put the keys directly in the sentence, because i dont know how works .boto file...

Can somebody help me whit that, please? And explain the whole process to me so this works?? I really apreciate this... It would be very helpful for me!

Thak you so much.